mongodb same query on different table efficiency problem
I have a MongoDB query caching issue. There are two identical tables, a and b, with the same structure, indexes, and similar data. Queries with the same conditions are very slow on table b, but fast on table a. I tried analyzing the queries, but both queries have the same execution plan; the only difference is that the memory consumption for table a is greater than that for table b.
Additionally, there's a caching issue. After executing a query once, the query on table b runs quickly, but after a while, about 10 minutes later, the query becomes slow again, while table a does not. I checked the configuration file settings, and memory is not specified, so it should be the default settings. Currently, the memory usage is at 48%.
mongodb version: 3.4.5
os:centos 7
here is the executionstats
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "cninfo.combined_stock_news_v1",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "is_delete" : {
                    "$eq" : "0"
                }
            },
            {
                "tags.stock_code" : {
                    "$eq" : "SH601211"
                }
            },
            {
                "version" : {
                    "$lte" : 9.62
                }
            },
            {
                "$nor" : [
                    {
                        "type" : {
                            "$eq" : "big_news"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "limitAmount" : 20,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "type" : {
                                "$eq" : "big_news"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "type" : 1,
                        "version" : 1,
                        "timestamp" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version_v1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ],
                        "version" : [ ],
                        "timestamp" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                        "version" : [ "[-inf.0, 9.619999999999999]" ],
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "timestamp" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "is_delete" : {
                                    "$eq" : "0"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "tags.stock_code" : {
                                    "$eq" : "SH601211"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "version" : {
                                    "$lte" : 9.62
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "type" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "type_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "type" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "timestamp" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "$nor" : [
                                    {
                                        "type" : {
                                            "$eq" : "big_news"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "version" : {
                                    "$lte" : 9.62
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                            "type" : 1,
                            "is_delete" : 1,
                            "publish_time" : -1,
                            "timestamp" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "tags.stock_code_1_type_1_is_delete_1_publish_time_-1_timestamp_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                            "type" : [ ],
                            "is_delete" : [ ],
                            "publish_time" : [ ],
                            "timestamp" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                            "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                            "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                            "publish_time" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ],
                            "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "is_delete" : {
                                "$eq" : "0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "tags.stock_code" : {
                                "$eq" : "SH601211"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "version" : {
                                "$lte" : 9.62
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$nor" : [
                                {
                                    "type" : {
                                        "$eq" : "big_news"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "timestamp" : -1,
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "publish_time" : 1,
                        "type" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "timestamp_-1_tags.stock_code_1_is_delete_1_publish_time_1_type_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "timestamp" : [ ],
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "publish_time" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ],
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "publish_time" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 20,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 4334,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 5867,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 5865,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "nReturned" : 20,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2484,
        "works" : 5889,
        "advanced" : 20,
        "needTime" : 5868,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 244,
        "restoreState" : 244,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "sortPattern" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "memUsage" : 31056,
        "memLimit" : 33554432,
        "limitAmount" : 20,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "nReturned" : 5865,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2474,
            "works" : 5868,
            "advanced" : 5865,
            "needTime" : 2,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 244,
            "restoreState" : 244,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "type" : {
                                "$eq" : "big_news"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 5865,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2464,
                "works" : 5867,
                "advanced" : 5865,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 244,
                "restoreState" : 244,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 5865,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 5865,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                    "works" : 5867,
                    "advanced" : 5865,
                    "needTime" : 1,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 244,
                    "restoreState" : 244,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "type" : 1,
                        "version" : 1,
                        "timestamp" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version_v1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ],
                        "version" : [ ],
                        "timestamp" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                        "version" : [ "[-inf.0, 9.619999999999999]" ],
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 5867,
                    "seeks" : 2,
                    "dupsTested" : 5865,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "indexDef" : {
                        "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version_v1",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                            "is_delete" : [ ],
                            "type" : [ ],
                            "version" : [ ],
                            "timestamp" : [ ]
                        },
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                            "is_delete" : 1,
                            "type" : 1,
                            "version" : 1,
                            "timestamp" : -1
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "ecs-zxzx-0011",
    "port" : 29999,
    "version" : "3.4.5",
    "gitVersion" : "520b8f3092c48d934f0cd78ab5f40fe594f96863"
},
"ok" : 1

}
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "cninfo.combined_stock_news",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "is_delete" : {
                    "$eq" : "0"
                }
            },
            {
                "tags.stock_code" : {
                    "$eq" : "SH601211"
                }
            },
            {
                "version" : {
                    "$lte" : 9.62
                }
            },
            {
                "$nor" : [
                    {
                        "type" : {
                            "$eq" : "big_news"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "limitAmount" : 20,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "type" : {
                                "$eq" : "big_news"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "type" : 1,
                        "version" : 1,
                        "timestamp" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ],
                        "version" : [ ],
                        "timestamp" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                        "version" : [ "[-inf.0, 9.619999999999999]" ],
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "timestamp" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "is_delete" : {
                                    "$eq" : "0"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "tags.stock_code" : {
                                    "$eq" : "SH601211"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "version" : {
                                    "$lte" : 9.62
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "type" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "type_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "type" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "timestamp" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "$nor" : [
                                    {
                                        "type" : {
                                            "$eq" : "big_news"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "version" : {
                                    "$lte" : 9.62
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                            "type" : 1,
                            "is_delete" : 1,
                            "publish_time" : -1,
                            "timestamp" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "tags.stock_code_1_type_1_is_delete_1_publish_time_-1_timestamp_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                            "type" : [ ],
                            "is_delete" : [ ],
                            "publish_time" : [ ],
                            "timestamp" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                            "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                            "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                            "publish_time" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ],
                            "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 20,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "is_delete" : {
                                "$eq" : "0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "tags.stock_code" : {
                                "$eq" : "SH601211"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "version" : {
                                "$lte" : 9.62
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$nor" : [
                                {
                                    "type" : {
                                        "$eq" : "big_news"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "timestamp" : -1,
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "publish_time" : 1,
                        "type" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "timestamp_-1_tags.stock_code_1_is_delete_1_publish_time_1_type_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "timestamp" : [ ],
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "publish_time" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ],
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "publish_time" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 20,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 189,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 5906,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 5904,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "nReturned" : 20,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 122,
        "works" : 5928,
        "advanced" : 20,
        "needTime" : 5907,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 185,
        "restoreState" : 185,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "sortPattern" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "memUsage" : 198166,
        "memLimit" : 33554432,
        "limitAmount" : 20,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "nReturned" : 5904,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 122,
            "works" : 5907,
            "advanced" : 5904,
            "needTime" : 2,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 185,
            "restoreState" : 185,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "type" : {
                                "$eq" : "big_news"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 5904,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 111,
                "works" : 5906,
                "advanced" : 5904,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 185,
                "restoreState" : 185,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 5904,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 5904,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                    "works" : 5906,
                    "advanced" : 5904,
                    "needTime" : 1,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 185,
                    "restoreState" : 185,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                        "is_delete" : 1,
                        "type" : 1,
                        "version" : 1,
                        "timestamp" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ ],
                        "type" : [ ],
                        "version" : [ ],
                        "timestamp" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "tags.stock_code" : [ "[\"SH601211\", \"SH601211\"]" ],
                        "is_delete" : [ "[\"0\", \"0\"]" ],
                        "type" : [ "[MinKey, \"big_news\")", "(\"big_news\", MaxKey]" ],
                        "version" : [ "[-inf.0, 9.619999999999999]" ],
                        "timestamp" : [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 5906,
                    "seeks" : 2,
                    "dupsTested" : 5904,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "indexDef" : {
                        "indexName" : "idx_stock_code_is_delete_type_version",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : [ "tags.stock_code" ],
                            "is_delete" : [ ],
                            "type" : [ ],
                            "version" : [ ],
                            "timestamp" : [ ]
                        },
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "tags.stock_code" : 1,
                            "is_delete" : 1,
                            "type" : 1,
                            "version" : 1,
                            "timestamp" : -1
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "ecs-zxzx-0011",
    "port" : 29999,
    "version" : "3.4.5",
    "gitVersion" : "520b8f3092c48d934f0cd78ab5f40fe594f96863"
},
"ok" : 1

}
I wonder how does the cache about table b is losing so fast or how can I make table a and table b behavior consistent

Maybe update to more recent version of MongoDB. Version 3.4.5 is way outdated.

The difference is right there in the execution stats.  Both queries took ~10ms to scan the index, then one took 111ms fetching the documents, while the other took 2.4 seconds.
